# How do I test props in a React stateless functional component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6, jestjs

With Jest and Enzyme, I am trying to test that my *Logo* component receives the right props (`id`, `height`, `width`, `active`, `disableTransparency`).

I have tried creating an instance (`wrapper.instance()`), but this returns null. I have also tried `wrapper.getElement().props`, and this returns the props for the components rendered.

```
const Logo = ({id, height, width, active, disableTransparency}) => (
    <Svg x='0px' y='0px' height={height} width={width} viewBox='0 0 1000 1000'>
        {(active) && <Gradient id={id}/>}
        {(disableTransparency) && <Underlay/>}
        <Overlay id={id} active={active}/>
    </Svg>
);
```

Comment: You could use jest “called with”? As a functional component is just a function it kinda doesn’t matter if it receives the props, but rather what it does with them.

Comment: Also I don’t think “functional components” don’t have instances, which is why they don’t have access to life cycle methods.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `wrapper.props()`?  This is how I typically get at a component's props when using Enzyme.

Comment: I have tried that too. It returns the props passed to the Svg, Gradient, and Overlay components. I would like to get the props passed to the Logo component itself, e.g. with a normal React component, the props passed to it can be retrieved by doing `wrapper.instance().props.id`.

Comment: That's probably because you are doing shallow rendering. You should try to do a full rendering with mount and not shallw

Comment: @Foyarash, you're right I am using `shallow()`. I'm testing ReactNative and unfortunately Enzyme does not support running `mount()` with RN components.